# Visual Studio Browser Link not working in Firefox

Tags: visual-studio, firefox, web-essentials

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Browser Link doesn't work with Firefox. 
IE and Chrome work perfectly with Browser Link.

Just got a new machine, but that didn't help either.

I tried the prerequisites mentioned in the browserlink dashboard (for static files, enable debugging) and I use IIS express, so .NET 4.0 is there.

Are there any more settings needed in Firefox?

In the network view, I just don't receive a response from the server, 0 bytes transferred.

Network trace:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it, the main website was running on 44300, browserlink seems to run on 44399 (although that port isn't visible in IIS express)

[image]

Browse to https://localhost:44399 gave me the Firefox "This Connection is Untrusted" screen, where I needed to trust("confirm security exception") the self signed IIS certificate (just like what I had done on the https://localhost:44300 site)

So it seems Firefox remembers trusted certificates per port number, not per DNS/IP/Name like IE and Chrome seem to do.

Now the browserlink is working and downloading the files.

Comment: Another way to fix it, if you don't know what he is talking about, sorry Erik :D, is to Copy the Link you are using (https://localhost:44393), stop the IIS and then browse to this link. The message with the Certificate will appear again and you will tell the browser again, that you trust this. When you did it, he will not find the site (how should he if IIS is down). Then you can restart and it will work. It worked fine for me in VS2017

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IIS running locally, but ran into a similar problem running the app locally with Visual Studio 2019.

The suggestion by Erik fixed the problem for me as well. Browsing to https://localhost:44399/ and accepting the certificate worked in Firefox Developer.

Some more details from Microsoft regarding self-signed certificates:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/handling-url-binding-failures-in-iis-express

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).